# How to setup a permalink structure for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I would like to know the correct way to setup the permalink structure for a custom post type.

Is there any attribute I am to set when I run a register_post_type() ?

e.g.

```
custom post type: product
expected permalink structure: /product/<slug>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the *rewrite* argument.

Here's an example setting the url to *tips*

```
$args = array(
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true, 
    'show_in_menu' => true, 
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tips' ), // Here!
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields')
  ); 

  register_post_type( 'tips', $args );
```

More info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Ah I see. So this will make the permalink structure "/tips/<slug>" ?

Comment: Yes, this will create: youdomain.com/tips/my-tip

Comment: And also, if I have the single-tips.php that would be the template for this post_type right ?

Comment: You can have **archive-tips.php** and **single-tips.php** Check out: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Comment: Wonderful ! Thanks. What an amazing software wordpress is !